# Why are my render and preview images different? The preview is better

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, render-passes

The low pixel version is the preview screen, which is clear but has lighter colors. The high-quality version is the rendered image, and both are using the Cycles renderer. The preview have more details and colors event with pixels. I don't understand why.  What could be causing this?
Thank you.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have some compositing nodes, and possibly a denoise?

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I've tried a denoise. There was worse. And I don't use any compositing :(

Comment: Try copying the noise threshold and max samples settings from viewport to render settings and render again. That sould at least make the render as noisy as the preview if you like it. Not sure why the colors would be different without compositing though. Is your screenshot showing the render from blender, or from a picture file you opened?

Comment: for the color problem, there was a similar question here: https://blenderartists.org/t/ffmpeg-desaturation/1370535 I suppose you are in Standard color management and not Filmic?

Comment: @L0Lock Thank you . I think I find the problem. That is because of the camera focus empty object is far from the face. I don't realise that...